# Problem with displaying adMob on Android with Phonegap + Jquery

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to ask:
I read all complete article here:
http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

But I still cannot display in my App.

I checked that:

I have permisions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Next, that I have filled pubid in script and other next things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var admob_vars = {
    pubid: 'asdadf5d29443', // publisher id
    test: false, // test mode, set to false if non-test mode
    manual_mode: true
  };
</script>
```

Everything seems O.K, but I still don't see any ad on display.